# Using layers with different CRS in Intersection tool of QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, intersection

I've always thought that to intersect two layers, they needed to have the same CRS.

Today, I tested the Intersection tool to intersect layers with different CRSs, and I was surprised to see that it always returned the correct intersection. It happened when I intersected a layer with a geographic CRS with another layer with a projected CRS (even when they had a different datum).

It happened with layers I've created, and with layers I've downloaded from official data providers.

Do QGIS reproject layers on the fly even when using a tool like Intersection?

That's not what I learned years ago.

Comment: Just like you QGIS learned a lot over the past years.

Comment: It might still be a good idea to have both layers in the same CRS for precision etc. - doesn't it?

Comment: I guess so, but I haven't found any mention of it on the QGIS documentation so I really don't know what criteria apply. I've always thought that without having the same CRS, the intersection tool wouldn't work, but I tried it in different scenarios, and it seemed to work very well. I didn't expect it. It looks like the on-the-fly projection not only is applied when uploading layers but also when applying tools, doesn't it?